# Prestashop clear cache which folders affected

Tags: php, caching, smarty, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I searched a lot for this question and i didn't found the correct answer for Prestashop 1.6, i have made a script to clear Prestashop cache, smarty cache,
I got the code from adminPerformances controller,

```
Tools::clearSmartyCache();
Tools::clearXMLCache();
Media::clearCache();
Tools::generateIndex();
```

I read that it cleared the cache from /cache/smarty/cache, but when executing the script or clicking in clear cache in performances page it doesn't remove subfolders from this folder.
Any body knows 'clear cache' will affect which folders/files.

Thanks.

Comment: In my case (PS 1.6.1.6), it only removes some folders but not all folders. In `cache/smarty/compile`, do you see if `last_flush` is updated when you call `Tools::clearSmartyCache();`

Answer (score 1):

Prestashop uses a system called Lazy Cache.

Here is the `clearAllCache` and `clearCache` methods of `/classes/SmartyCustom` classe:

```php
public function clearAllCache($exp_time = null, $type = null)
{
    Db::getInstance()->execute('REPLACE INTO `'._DB_PREFIX_.'smarty_last_flush` (`type`, `last_flush`) VALUES (\'template\', FROM_UNIXTIME('.time().'))');
    return $this->delete_from_lazy_cache(null, null, null);
}

public function clearCache($template_name, $cache_id = null, $compile_id = null, $exp_time = null, $type = null)
{
    return $this->delete_from_lazy_cache($template_name, $cache_id, $compile_id);
}

public function delete_from_lazy_cache($template, $cache_id, $compile_id)
{
    if (!$template) {
        return Db::getInstance()->execute('TRUNCATE TABLE `'._DB_PREFIX_.'smarty_lazy_cache`', false);
    }

    $template_md5 = md5($template);
    $sql          = 'DELETE FROM `'._DB_PREFIX_.'smarty_lazy_cache`
                        WHERE template_hash=\''.pSQL($template_md5).'\'';

    if ($cache_id != null) {
        $sql .= ' AND cache_id LIKE "'.pSQL((string)$cache_id).'%"';
    }

    if ($compile_id != null) {
        if (strlen($compile_id) > 32) {
            $compile_id = md5($compile_id);
        }
        $sql .= ' AND compile_id="'.pSQL((string)$compile_id).'"';
    }
    Db::getInstance()->execute($sql, false);
    return Db::getInstance()->Affected_Rows();
}
```

As you can see, cache files are indexed in database under table `smarty_lazy_cache`. And the cache file is never deleted, only unindexed from the table.

Comment: This is for mysql or file system cache?

Comment: For Smarty file system cache. As you can see in table `smaty_lazy_cache` the `filepath` column contains the path to the cache file.

Comment: I saw the table, it is empty, i deleted accidentally the cache/smarty/ folder and recreated it but always it is empty have you a solution? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Even with no cache option on it still creates cache files in the fowllowing folders:

```
/cache/smarty/cache
/cache/smarty/compile
```

I think that `Smarty_Internal_Utility::clearCompiledTemplate` should delete those files. Which is called by `Tools::clearSmartyCache()`

But anyway, what bugs me the most, is even with no cache option on and force compile, most times I need to manually clear the cache. Normally by deleting the folders I mentioned above (it's faster, specially on a virtual machine locally).
This issue is still a "bug" in 1.7.

Speaking of 1.7, the cache is in `/app/cache`, and there is one for dev and one for prod. where it's even cached translations, class_index.php, and a lot of more stuff than in 1.6 cache.

Comment: As i wrote in my question i tried Tools::clearSmartyCache(); but it didn't clear the /cache/smarty/cache and /cache/smarty/compile subfolders

Answer (score 0):

As per our knowledge the only folder that is affected while clearing cache from the admin panel.

```
/cache/smarty/compile
```

Please let us know if we are wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Prestashop 1.7 (tested on 1.7.6.1)

- widely proposed solutions **does not remove smarty template cache** (files under `_PS_ROOT_DIR_ . '/var/cache/' . $env . '/'`)

To correctly reproduce the functionality of the "Clear cache" button in Admin > Advanced Parameters > Performance, it should be like this:

```
include('../../../config/config.inc.php');
include('../../../init.php');


Tools::clearAllCache(); // <---- this is the trick
Tools::clearXMLCache();
Media::clearCache();
Tools::generateIndex();
```

What I was missing in other answers is to be calling `Tools::clearSf2Cache()` which is called from inside `Tools::clearAllCache();` in my example above.

`Tools::clearSf2Cache()` removes also files under `_PS_ROOT_DIR_ . '/var/cache/' . $env . '/'`

**So if you want to also remove smarty template FILES, go with my answer**

**Background/explanation:**

"Clear cache" button calls `PerformanceController::clearCacheAction()` inside it calls `CacheClearerChain::clear()` which calls these:

- PrestaShop\PrestaShop\Adapter\Cache\Clearer\SymfonyCacheClearer
- PrestaShop\PrestaShop\Adapter\Cache\Clearer\SmartyCacheClearer
- PrestaShop\PrestaShop\Adapter\Cache\Clearer\XmlCacheClearer
- PrestaShop\PrestaShop\Adapter\Cache\Clearer\MediaCacheClearer
- PrestaShop\PrestaShop\Adapter\Cache\Clearer\ClassIndexCacheClearer

And this is basically the same as my proposed solution above.